# Mapping doctrine native query to none Entity model class

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to use native query in doctrine and for now created something really simple:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult('ObjectA', 'a');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'id', 'id');
$query = $em->createNativeQuery('SELECT * FROM table a', $rsm);
```

What I try using this code, I am getting an error that ObjectA is not a valid entity or mapped super class. Which is totally true. 
My question is: Is there any way to mad result of a native query to any arbitrary class (not Entity), but still user Doctrine's tools to do it.

Note: I am trying to avoid usage of lower level PDO.

Thank you.

Comment: probably you need to select the specific field you defined so try this: `$query = $em->createNativeQuery('SELECT id FROM table a', $rsm);`

Comment: It is not helping... It looks like I must define the class as an entity.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing like that, neither in the doc nor in the source code `Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping` (and it happens that some features are not documented).
I'd go with using [scalar results](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#scalar-results) and mapping the query result back to the object. Something like this:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addScalarResult('a', 'a');
$rsm->addScalarResult('b', 'b');
$query = $em->createNativeQuery('SELECT a, b FROM table LIMIT 1', $rsm);
$result = $query->getSingleResult();
$a = new ObjectA();
$a->setA($result['a']);
// or
$a = new ObjectA($result); // with mapping passed to the constructor
```

Comment: This works, but it means that I need to make the conversion into an object myself. Not the bast case for us...